# command ls with pattern in a function is not working in R

Tags: r

I am trying following function:

```
srch = function(srchstr){
    print(ls(pattern=srchstr))
}
```

While following works:

```
ls(pattern='ddf')
[1] "ddf"
```

Calling the function produces following output:

```
srch('ddf')
character(0)
```

I tried following methods:

```
ss = srch('ddf')
character(0)

ss
character(0)

print(ss)
character(0)

unlist(ss)
character(0)

sapply(ss, print)
named list()

sapply(ss, cat)
named list()

cat(ss)
```

'cat(ss)' simply gives no output!

Why is this happening & how can this be corrected?

Comment: From the documentation of `?ls`: "By default, the environment of the call to ls or objects is used." and elsewhere: "When invoked with no argument inside a function, ls returns the names of the function's local variables: this is useful in conjunction with browser."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to look in the `.GlobalEnv`:

```
srch = function(srchstr){
    print(ls(pattern=srchstr, envir = .GlobalEnv))
}
```

**edit** joran was faster...