# how to make function in R to remove all objects from global environment except defaults and objects passed as arguments

Tags: r

I'm new to R (and programming in general), so I've been making various functions to warm myself up to it.

I've been trying to figure out how to make an R function that will clear my global environment of all objects except for a specified few.  The code I've seen others use for this looks something like:

```
rm(list= ls()[!(ls() %in% c('keepThis','andThis'))],envir = )
```

But whenever I put this in a function (with no arguments), the function won't remove *anything* from the global environment. I'd like to understand why.

I've had more luck with:

```
clean <- function(except){
    except = ifelse(is.character(except), except, deparse(substitute(except)))
    rm(list=setdiff(ls(envir=.GlobalEnv), c(except,"clean")), envir=.GlobalEnv)
}
```

But I can't figure out how to modify this one to allow me to save more than two objects at a time.

Ideally, I would love to have a function that would save several specified objects by default, as well as any objects passed as arguments. Is this even possible?

Comment: `ls()` will show objects in the evaluation frame by default.  Try `ls(envir=globalenv())` if you want global objects.  Similarly, you'll need to say where `rm()` should work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [command ls with pattern in a function is not working in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26591184/command-ls-with-pattern-in-a-function-is-not-working-in-r)

Comment: How are you passing arguments to clean? Are you passing a vector of character values?

Comment: @MrFlick I was originally trying to make a function in which I could pass all objects I wanted to save as their own argument, by using the ... argument, but I haven't quite figured out how that would work, and I'm definitely open to passing a vector of character values too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this function may help:

```
rm.except <- function(except, pattern) {
  except = except
  pattern = pattern
  formula = c(c(except), ls(pattern = pattern, envir = .GlobalEnv))
  rm(list = setdiff(ls(envir = .GlobalEnv), formula), envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

ls() in my environment:

```
 [1] "a"          "al"         "b"          "c"          "corrmatrix" "counts"    
 [7] "d"          "df1"        "df2"        "e"          "f"
```

I want all objects to be removed; except for objects a, b, c, d and those objects containing *df*;

```
rm.except(except = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), pattern = "df")
```

ls() will be:

```
[1] "a"   "b"   "c"   "d"   "df1" "df2"
```

Comment: This is even more versatile than I was looking for, and by giving "except" and "pattern" default values, it does exactly what I want. Thanks!!

Comment: I am glad that I could help u. Then please accept it, if you think it is good enough, so other users will also know the answer.